# quicksort on singly-linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

My quickSort doesn't work. I'm particularly unsure about what to pass through to the partition algorithm and how to manage the pivot as in one case it becomes a header node and in the other case a last node. I based my approach on the solution for arrays. Here's my attempt. Any ideas? Please note that the partioning algorithm was chosen to suit the one-directional nature of a singly-linked list(SLL).

```
public static SLL quickSort(SLL list, SLLNode first, SLLNode last)
{
    if (first != null && last != null)
    {
        SLLNode p = partition(list, first, last) ;
        quickSort(list,first,p) ;
        quickSort(list,p.succ, last) ;
    }
    return list ;
}

public static SLLNode partition(SLL list, SLLNode first, SLLNode last)
{
    //last.succ = null ;
    SLLNode p = first ;
    SLLNode ptr = p.succ ;

    while (ptr!=null)
    {
        if (ptr.data.compareToIgnoreCase(p.data)<0)
        {
            String pivot = p.data ;
            p.data =  ptr.data ;
            ptr.data = p.succ.data ;
            p.succ.data = pivot ;
            p = p.succ ;
        }
        ptr = ptr.succ ;
    }
    return p ;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

- I want to do this 'in-place'
- I am looking for help specifically on how to manage head and last in this process.
- Please don't suggest alternatives unless my approach is imposible

Comment: When you step through the code in you debugger what do you see?  What is the simplest example you can have which doesn't work?  Can you provide a unit test which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You want an in-place sort on singly linked list? This will come out very slow. If you can trade some memory against time and a clear algorithm, then make it so that partition actually creates two new sublists, sort them recursively and concatenate the results.

Comment: I think the " last.succ = null" will break the linked-list.

Comment: @all, " last.succ = null" now commented out - it was just an other of my attempts to find a way to deal with incoming head and last.

Comment: @Ingo, indeeed i want to try this 'in-place', just like the array solution

Comment: @Baba If this is not just for fun I would strongly advise against doing that - think about the computational complexity of an array access versus a linked list access - and you'll have a lot of them.

Comment: @Ingo, i agree, it's not for fun & my aim is at this stage to understand how to manipulate head and last as they are passed through the partitioning algorithm, while at the same time not creating new lists

Comment: I feel you shoud not manipulate the list links as this is most likely destroying the list. You must only touch the elements, just like in the array solution.

Comment: @Ingo, hmm sounds like a good hint, so i will try to modify 'while (ptr!=null)' to  'while (ptr!=last.succ)' or something like that. have to shoot off to class now, will try later. in the meantime, thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure - is there any specific reason you aren't using a more appropiate algorithm such as Mergesort?

Comment: I disagree with Ingo - I think best way is to leave data unmodified, and when you partition relink the list into two lists

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach for a quicksort on linked lists would be to create two (or better three, the middle one being all elements equal to the pivot element) new lists in the partitioning step, sort the first and last recursively, and then concatenate them together.

Your code instead swaps the data inside the nodes ... interesting. I tried it with the following (sub)list:

```
        first                            last
        [ 5 ]-->[ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
```

Look here what your algorithm does:

```
        [ 5 ]-->[ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
          p
                 ptr

3<5? (yes) {
pivot=5
        [ 3 ]-->[ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
          p      ptr
        [ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
          p      ptr
        [ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 5 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
          p      ptr
        [ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 5 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
                  p
                 ptr
}
        [ 3 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 5 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 2 ]
                  p
                         ptr
```

This is the state after the first iteration. Since `ptr != null`, we now go in the next iteration, but I think you can already here see the problem. After the next iteration it looks like this:

```
        [ 3 ]-->[ 5 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 2 ]
                          p
                                 ptr
```

In the next iteration no swaps happen:

```
        [ 3 ]-->[ 5 ]-->[ 9 ]-->[ 7 ]-->[ 2 ]
                          p
                                         ptr
```

And now we will get a NullPointerException, since `ptr.next == null` (or if this is a sublist of a bigger list, we would swap outside of the limits).

So, some ideas:

- In the swapping step, you should make sure that afterwards `p` points to the node which now contains the pivot element.
- you should stop when reaching the `last` element, and make sure you don't swap after it (but that still the element itself is swapped if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

```
//logic - from left to right, remove smaller node and append at the beginning,
public void partition(int x)// x is your pivot element.
        {
            Node prev = null;
            Node cur = root;
            while (cur!=null)
            {
                if ( cur.data > x || cur == root)
                {
                    cur = cur.next;
                    prev = cur;
                }
                else
                {
                    Node next = cur.next;
                    if (prev != null) prev.next = next;
                    cur.next = root;
                    root = cur;
                    cur = next;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the line "last.succ = null". I think that you might want to find some other way to check if you've reached the end of the list segment you're partitioning. As it is, I think you should be getting a null-pointer exception, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-destructive version translate the following pseudocode into Java:

```
quickSort list
    | list.isEmpty = empty list
    | otherwise = concat (quickSort lower) (new List(pivot, quickSort upper))
    where
         pivot = list.head
         lower = list of elements from list.tail that are < pivot
         upper = list of elements from list.tail that are >= pivot
```